# Migrating to SQL Server 2017 : same query returns no rows sometimes

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2017, getdate, datetime2

I've just upgraded to SQL Server 2017 from SQL Server 2014 (only dev environment yet) and noticed a very strange behavior : the same query has two different impacts on both servers.

The query has been rewritten and reduced to the minimum for the example:

`SELECT * FROM eth_Mandate M 
 WHERE customerId = 1 
 AND M.isActive = 1`

The field `isActive` is a computed column (returning 1 if mandate is active, 0 otherwise) defined as:

```
[isActive]  AS (CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= ISNULL([man_start],GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() <= isnull(dateadd(day,(1),[man_stop]),GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

For SQL Server 2014 it always works. For 2017, once in 4-5 times it returns no rows as sometimes `isActive` is computed as 0.

Why? I've searched deeply and wanted to share it so you can find my own answer below the explanation I understood based on my tests.

Comment: Versions please. It is possible this has longbeen fixed and is an admin error. 2017 is under active management. Which versions are you using?

Comment: build 14.0.2002 for SQL Server 2017 and 12.0.4213 for SQL Server 2014 (I'm using a hosted dedicated and managed server in the cloud).

Comment: I trongly suggest, before asking the question, to upgrade to 14.0.3038.14 - 12 CU packagets in the future from yours (!). You literally run on RTM + 2 security updates, ignoring so 11 (!) bug fix packs. No sense in trying to fis code bugs unless they happen on CURRENT versions.

Comment: In the future check https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sqlserver/ for all build numbers and update accordingly ;) Helps to avoid bugs.

Comment: Thanks TomTom for your answers. I'll ask my provider to update with latest patch.

Comment: @pti_jul, I updated your answer to answer the "why" question you asked. Your answer included workarounds.

Comment: @DanGuzman : Thanks for this very interesting article !! I read it with lots of interest. Thanks for your suggestion, but changing the Compatibility level is something temporary (as mentioned in your article) until a proper solution is found. So, I've added Solution 4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the ISNULL we have a datetime2 (the field man_stop) and getdate as fallback (returns a datetime) and apprently the ISNULL cast the second param based on the first param....Consequently, we are comparing the getdate() as datetime with a getdate() as datetime2.
Note that the man_stop (end of the customer mandate) is most of the time not null as the mandate are running.

Then, you must take a look at [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/#fourth) and specifically about the sentence :

> As for the time portion, SQL Server starts with 0 and increments the numeric value **for each .003 seconds** after midnight. 
>   Means what ? if the time is 12:15:00:002 is actually stored as 12:15:00:003 but compared with 12:15:00.002 so not equal !!

**SOLUTION 1**

So, to fix the problem for SQL Server 2017 (no problem with SQL Server 2014 though), I simply converted my fields datetime2 to datetime to have a correct comparison with getdate() as datetime :

```
[isActive]  AS (case when getdate()>=isnull(CONVERT([datetime],[man_start]),getdate()) AND getdate()<=isnull(dateadd(day,(1),CONVERT([datetime],[man_stop])),getdate()) then (1) else (0) end)
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Or I could also convert all the datetime to datetime2. Instead of GETDATE() use SYSDATETIME() returning a datetime2(7). As my two fields are simply datetime2 (no precision defined) the comparison was worse...but when converting the datetime2 to datetime2(7) it was running like a charm. So it becomes :

```
(case when SYSDATETIME () >= isnull(convert(datetime2(7), [man_start]),SYSDATETIME()) AND SYSDATETIME() <= isnull(dateadd(day,(1),convert(datetime2(7), [man_stop])),SYSDATETIME()) then (1) else (0) end)
```

**SOLUTION 3**

Change the [database compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) to 120 or lower to preserve the legacy behavior when comparing datetime and datetime 2 types. This [breaking change](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-2016-and-azure-sql-database-v12-breaking-change/) was introduced in SQL Server 2016.

**SOLUTION 4 (solution applied)**

Use same type of data and avoid type conversion. 
Change the type of the fields `man_start` and `man_stop` as datetime2(7) (instead of datetime2 which is datetime2(3)) to match SYSDATETIME() function returned type (datetime2(7)).

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN [man_start] datetime2(7) NULL
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN [man_stop] datetime2(7) NULL
```

So my computed column becomes : 
    [isActive]  AS (CASE WHEN SYSDATETIME() >= ISNULL([man_start],SYSDATETIME()) AND SYSDATETIME() <= isnull(dateadd(day,(1),[man_stop]),SYSDATETIME()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Advantages : Compatibility level remains, avoid type conversion (better peformance)

Comment: So, all kinds of information about what `isActive` actually is? That ought to be **in the question**. Your question, as it stands at the moment is "why does `isActive` sometimes not work" with *no further information about it*. This makes this question/answer pair very poor quality at the moment.

Comment: You're right. I firstly had all together and decided finally to separate question and own answer...but missed that point. I've edited both question and answer to include the `IsActive` field definition in the question.